# Can template alias be used as a function input type?

Tags: c++, templates, generics

I am wondering if it is possible to have a template alias as a function input type, and the 'further' type can be further determined based on the input?

```cpp
template<typename T>
using Vec = std::vector<T>;
```

I want to define a function:

```
void func(Vec& a){
  for(auto &each :a){
    //Do something
  }
}
```

Where the type of `Vec` can be derived based on the input `a`.

In such an example, the same `func` can be applied to all `a` as `std::vector<ANY TYPE>`.

I have such an issue because I have a `vec` initialized at the first beginning and run a series of functions.

```
a = Vec<int>;
fun1(a);
fun2(a);
...
funN(a);
```

I want to have the same operations but with different types.

```
a = Vec<double>;
fun1(a);
fun2(a);
...
funN(a);
```

If I follow the old templated function it will be

```
a = Vec<int>;
fun1<int>(a);
fun2<int>(a);
...
funN<int>(a);
```

and to change to `double` I have to do

```
a = Vec<double>;
fun1<double>(a);
fun2<double>(a);
...
funN<double>(a);
```

Basically, I have to change `int` to `double` for each function. I am looking forward some easier ways to do so.

Comment: Anything wrong with a plain old templated function? `template<typename T> void func(Vec<T>&)`?

Comment: `Vec` can't be used as a type without supplying a template parameter to instantiate it with.

Comment: If I have multiple func-s but they will be used as the same type of some ```vec``` I set at the first beginning . Won't be a little cumbersome every time I have to type the type (```func1<T>) in calling each function?

Comment: @Ethanabc Your question makes no sense, please provide a [mcve] that you are trying to solve.

Comment: Re: _"If I follow the old templated function it will be"_, no, that's not required. Have you tried creating a template function? Are you aware that C++ has [template argument deduction](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/template_argument_deduction)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks to [template argument deduction](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/template_argument_deduction), templates already behave in the way that you want.

Defining `func` as

```
template<typename T>
void func(Vec<T>& a) {
    // ...
}
```

will let you write

```
Vec<int> a{};
func(a);

Vec<double> b{};
func(b);
```

No explicit type parameters are required at the call-site.